# how to debug BroadcastReceiver when app never was started after reboot?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a BroadcastReceiver which catches received SMS.

It works well, however, only in cases when the phone was just restarted and the app never started yet then - when the receiver catches a SMS I get a crash on the phone.

Since the app process is not running yet there is no way to attach DDMS to the app beforehand.

What is the "trick" to debug this case?

Many thanks!

Comment: you have any issue in starting application by registering RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED receiver?

Comment: Logs, try/catch and log exceptions..

Comment: OP didn't say that he's starting the app at boot time. He said that he's got a BroadcastReceiver that crashes the first time it is run after boot.

Comment: You could also post the code of your BroadcastReceiver onReceive(). Maybe there is something obvious there.

Comment: right, no issue when starting the app - closing it again. Logs are not possible. It seems that the context passed in the receiver is null in these cases... Just checked for that now and no crash - but need to dig deeper - thanks.